# Evaluating $\lim_{y \to 0^+} (\cosh (3/y))^y$

Tags: trigonometry, limits

> Evaluating $$\lim_{y \to 0^+} (\cosh (3/y))^y$$

This is what I have tried:

$L = (cosh(3/y))^y$

$\ln L = \frac{\cosh(3/y)}{1/y}$, applying L'Hopital's rule, I get:

$\ln L = \frac{-3y^2(\sinh (3/y))}{(y^2)}$

$\ln L = 3\sinh (3/y)$

Now I seem to be stuck in a loop between $\sinh$ and cosh. I know the answer is supposed to be $e^3$, but how do I proceed from here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You took the logarithm of $L$, but not of $\operatorname{cosh}$.

Comment: Oh jeez, you are totally right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\cosh(3/y)^y
&=\left(\frac{e^{3/y}+e^{-3/y}}{2}\right)^y\\
&=e^3\left(\frac{1+e^{-6/y}}{2}\right)^y
\end{align}
$$